# Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

Please could someone help me work out how to get started with JSONP?

Code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var pm_url = 'http://twitter.com/status';
    pm_url += '/user_timeline/stephenfry.json';
    pm_url += '?count=10&callback=photos';
    var photos = function (data) {
     alert(data);
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: pm_url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'photos',
        jsonp: false,
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R7EPt/6/

Should produce an alert, as far as I can work out from the documentation: isn't (but isn't producing any errors either).

thanks.

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: pm_url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: photos,
        jsonp: false,
    }); You had entered photos as a string.

Answer (score 400):

**JSONP** is really a simply trick to overcome **XMLHttpRequest** same domain policy. (As you know one cannot send **AJAX (XMLHttpRequest)** request to a different domain.)

So - instead of using **XMLHttpRequest** we have to use **script** HTMLl tags, the ones you usually use to load JS files, in order for JS to get data from another domain. Sounds weird?

Thing is - turns out **script** tags can be used in a fashion similar to **XMLHttpRequest**! Check this out:

```
script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://www.someWebApiServer.com/some-data";
```

You will end up with a **script** segment that looks like this after it loads the data:

```
<script>
{['some string 1', 'some data', 'whatever data']}
</script>
```

However this is a bit inconvenient, because we have to fetch this array from **script** tag. So **JSONP** creators decided that this will work better (and it is):

```
script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://www.someWebApiServer.com/some-data?callback=my_callback";
```

Notice *my_callback* function over there? So - when **JSONP** server receives your request and finds callback parameter - instead of returning plain JS array it'll return this:

```
my_callback({['some string 1', 'some data', 'whatever data']});
```

See where the profit is: now we get automatic callback (*my_callback*) that'll be triggered once we get the data.
   That's all there is to know about **JSONP**: it's a callback and script tags.

---

**NOTE:

These are simple examples of JSONP usage,  these are not production ready scripts.**

**RAW JavaScript demonstration (simple Twitter feed using JSONP):**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'twitterFeed'></div>
        <script>
        function myCallback(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
            var text = '';
            var len = dataWeGotViaJsonp.length;
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                twitterEntry = dataWeGotViaJsonp[i];
                text += '<p><img src = "' + twitterEntry.user.profile_image_url_https +'"/>' + twitterEntry['text'] + '</p>'
            }
            document.getElementById('twitterFeed').innerHTML = text;
        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/padraicb.json?count=10&callback=myCallback"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Basic jQuery example (simple Twitter feed using JSONP):**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/padraicb.json?count=10',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
                        var text = '';
                        var len = dataWeGotViaJsonp.length;
                        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                            twitterEntry = dataWeGotViaJsonp[i];
                            text += '<p><img src = "' + twitterEntry.user.profile_image_url_https +'"/>' + twitterEntry['text'] + '</p>'
                        }
                        $('#twitterFeed').html(text);
                    }
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'twitterFeed'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSONP** stands for **JSON with Padding**. (very poorly named technique as it really has nothing to do with what most people would think of as “padding”.)

Comment: This answer is now somewhat out of date because browsers now support `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers which allow regular Ajax calls to be made to some cross-origin domains.

Comment: Keep in mind you cannot do a form POST with JSONP. More info here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/08/27/jquery-post-jsonp-and-cross-domain-requests/

Comment: What do you have to consider if you want to make these scripts production-ready?

Comment: Wow, This is really helpful ! I finally get to know what exactly is JSONP and how does it work!

Answer (score 150):

There is even easier way how to work with JSONP using jQuery

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/something.json?callback=?", function(result){
   //response data are now in the result variable
   alert(result);
});
```

The `?` on the end of the URL tells jQuery that it is a JSONP request instead of JSON. jQuery registers and calls the callback function automatically.

For more detail refer to the [jQuery.getJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: @PetrPeller, Seems great but I don't seem to make a product out of it. Can you once see this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Az9SS/) It alerts no data. Maybe I missed something

Comment: @xDNP JSONP response must be supported by the server. Your sever does not seem to support it as I cannot see any added callback here: http://mylivecanvas.com/api/get_routes.php?date=2071-04-02&callback=test. Also you should use `&callback=?` as it's not the first parameter in your case.

Comment: @PetrPeller I am greatly interested on your solution. But, that does not work on me. I don't want to post a new question but it does not help me. What does **does not seem to support by server** mean? What should I do? And can you give me a complete URL that works for my server? I would be grateful on you. _Do I need any server configuration?_

Comment: @xDNP The server needs to respond with a specifically prepared response for JSONP. (Wrapping the response in a function call). I suggest reading about JSONP before continuing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: NICE! Very nice. I wasn't aware of this convention.

Comment: Why are you recommending not to use jQuery?

Comment: @JesusH You definitely can still use it for small and simple sites, but it does not offer tools for more complex single page applications.

Comment: What does the last edit, "Please don't use jQuery anymore!" mean?

Comment: It's now 2018, and I'm not sure what is supposed to even be used in 2017!

Comment: Think the Edit should be taken out, there's no restriction on JQuery unless it causes issues for your scenario.

Comment: Using this technique I get a syntax error in Chrome console; additionally, looking at Network tab I see something strange:  http://haya2now.jp/data/data.json?callback=jQuery1112017994359455628528_1543399440567&_=1543399440568


The numbers change at each call; the shorter ones are just unix timestamps, but what about the longest one?


Anyway, can this technique be used without knowing how the server is configured?

Answer (score 31):

In response to the OP, there are two problems with your code: you need to set jsonp='callback', and adding in a callback function in a variable like you did does not seem to work.

Update: when I wrote this the Twitter API was just open, but they changed it and it now requires authentication. I changed the second example to a working (2014Q1) example, but now using github.

This does not work any more - as an exercise, see if you can replace it with the Github API:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var pm_url = 'http://twitter.com/status';
    pm_url += '/user_timeline/stephenfry.json';
    pm_url += '?count=10&callback=photos';
    $.ajax({
        url: pm_url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'photos',
        jsonp: 'callback',
    });
});
function photos (data) {
    alert(data);
    console.log(data);
};
```

although alert()ing an array like that does not really work well... The "Net" tab in Firebug will show you the JSON properly. Another handy trick is doing

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

You can also use the **jQuery.getJSON** method. Here's a complete html example that gets a list of "gists" from github. This way it creates a randomly named callback function for you, that's the final "callback=?" in the url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JQuery (cross-domain) JSONP Twitter example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/gists?callback=?', function(response){
                    $.each(response.data, function(i, gist){
                        $('#gists').append('<li>' + gist.user.login + " (<a href='" + gist.html_url + "'>" + 
                            (gist.description == "" ? "undescribed" : gist.description) + '</a>)</li>');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="gists"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work anymore. Twitter changed their API.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<title>An JSONP example </title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- DIV FOR SHOWING IMAGES -->
<div id="images">
</div>
<!-- SCRIPT FOR GETTING IMAGES FROM FLICKER.COM USING JSONP -->
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
{
  format: "json"
},
//RETURNED RESPONSE DATA IS LOOPED AND ONLY IMAGE IS APPENDED TO IMAGE DIV
function(data) {
  $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
  $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");

 });
});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code helps in getting images from the Flicker API. This uses the GET method for getting images using JSONP. It can be found in detail in [here](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSONP.php#sthash.afh6OHZe.dpuf)