# Ajax calls makes Cross Domain trouble in Magento while using REST calls

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I am able to render JSON data in browser but when giving it as URL link in Javascript, it doesn't brings the data.

It shows null. The same thing happened when I use Java. I think this is the cross domain problem.

How to get resolve of this?

Answer (score 0):

Use CURL to get the Data's from Cross Domaim. Curl is more reliable and best method for cross domain data obtain.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to used jsonp. See [Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

You could also create a proxy, a simple php script on your web server that get the info from the remote server. See http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/examples/simple/