# External webservice call using jquery

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery, web, asmx

I have created a webservice in one application.Now i need to consume that in my another website .I know how it can be done if the webservice is in the same application like providing the url like "webservicename.asmx/getInventoryForWs" using jquery.
my jquery call code is

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/DashboardUI/Reports/Marketing/AUSUWs.asmx/getInventoryForWs",
            contentType: "application/json; charset="utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (ret) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Here is my vb.net webservice code

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the       
following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class AUSUWs
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function getInventoryForWs() As String
    Try
        Dim a As New AUSUReport
        Dim dt As DataTable = a.getInventoryForWs().Tables(0)
        Return (GetJson(dt))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
Public Function GetJson(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String
    Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = Nothing

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr(col))
        Next
        rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
End Function
End Class
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: use JSONP from cross domain requests AFAIK

Comment: if you dont mind can you please give me an exmple?i am new to this .Thanks in advance

Comment: Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6879276/309395) JSONP example

Comment: there is nothing wrong in the above code as far url is concern.

Comment: Dude but i am always getting errors..i am not getting the datas from that web service.

Comment: Could you please specify what errors you are getting. The above code looks right to me.

Comment: Status=error;error=undefined

Comment: This code will work fine if that web service is within our application.But here my requirement is loading from external web service

Answer (score 0):

I think this part is not correct with double slahes:

```
 url: "http://somewebsite.com//
       DashboardUI/Reports/Marketing/AUSUWs.asmx/getInventoryForWs",
```

Try this:

```
 url: "http://somewebsite.com/
       DashboardUI/Reports/Marketing/AUSUWs.asmx/getInventoryForWs",
```

Edit:

"dataType should be the type of what you receive but contentType should be the mime-type of what you are sending, the following should be ok"

```
JQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://somewebsite.com/DashboardUI/Reports/Marketing/AUSUWs.asmx/getInventoryForWs",       
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (ret) { 
              $(ret).find("Table").each(function () 
               { 
                   alert('success'); 
                   // $('#').val($(this).find('').text());
                });
        },
        error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Here is a detailed walkthrough. Do everything exact way like here and you won't have problem:
[Introduction to using jQuery with Web Services (VB.Net)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349598/Introduction-to-using-jQuery-with-Web-Services)

Comment: you post your data in xml to the service, and you get response in json?

Comment: ya, i need to load some datas from my external web service.Do you have any solution?

Comment: by the way data is plural by default so there is no word such as "datas"

Comment: can you get a more detailed exception from firebug? https://getfirebug.com/errors

Comment: I tried with your code,but still problem remains                     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/DashboardUI/Reports/Marketing/AUSUWs.asmx?getInventoryForWs",
                contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (ret) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
                }
            });

Comment: update you question with the new parameters what is localhost? use http before it

Comment: localhost should have a specific port, just try in your browser, if it's not loading in, it  won't work with ajax call. Does this loading in your browser? http://localhost/DashboardUI/Reports/Marketing/AUSUWs.asmx/

Comment: Ya it is loading and that is the web service url which i created in vb.net

Comment: Ok, but you didn't pass anything to the method. You don't have to specify the contenttype just remove it. I added to my code this modification.

Comment: my service is not hosted in the same web application path. 
And my code will work if my web services and my web application hosted in the same domain.But i need to do a cross-domain AJAX call

Comment: Exactly the same webservice should work cross-domain also, so there is something difference. Unless the consumer uses ssl, https, but the service owner don't provides.

Comment: So what shall i do now?Any solution?Thanks in advance

Comment: If I don't see the service, I can't help, but I think you can't provide it. So in that case you have to find the solution, I have no further idea. There must be a configuration error on the live service. If the live service is managed by another person, maybe you can ask for help.

Comment: You are not correct.My web service is working fine and it is showing the output as well and i have placed all of my service codes above.May i know what you are asking then ?