# POST RESTful api call from Javascript/Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, api

I'm trying to do a POST RESTful api call from a button on Javascript. The api call is cross domain, so that is a challenge. How do I make this call?

In ajax my call looks like: [I now know that you can't do cross-domain calls from ajax]:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'application/json',
                    accept: 'application/json',
                    async: false,
                    username: 'user',
                    password: 'name',
                    url: 'http://exterenal.website',
                    data: {
                        "name": "Marcus0.7",
                        "start": 500000,
                        "end": 1361640526000
                    },
                    success: function(){alert('DONE!');},
                    error:function(){alert('ERROR!')},
            });
```

in python the call looks like:

```
r = requests.post('http://externenal.website' ,headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) not json. The problem is that xmlhttprequest has a policy which states that you can't make a request outside of the current site domain. JSONP is a trick to get around this problem.

Be aware that you are breaking a safety policy.

[Here's a So post that explains how to do this using JQuery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)