# .ajax JSONP parsererror

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

I'm trying to use an ajax call to bring back data from a web api.  I wrote 2 similar functions and neither work.  I can see the data come back through Fiddler, but it won't go to the success call, for both of the functions below.  What am I doing wrong?  The data comes back in both functions in Fiddler, it just doesn't go to success.

Here is attempt 1:

```
    function PopulateDivisions()
{
    $.support.cors=true;


    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'http://IP/Service/api/DivisionSearch/GetAllDivisions',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',

        success: function(data) {

                alert(data);

                $("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val("-99").html("Select One"));
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                $("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Name).html(item.Name));
            });
        },
        error: function(xhrequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            alert("Original: " + thrownError + " : " + ErrorText);
        }
    });

}
```

Error: jQuery19102671239298189216_1382022403977 was not called : parser error

Here is the data Fiddler is showing comes back:

```
    [{"Id":1,"Description":"Executive","Name":"Executive "},{"Id":2,"Description":"ASD","Name":"Administrative Services Division "},{"Id":3,"Description":"COM","Name":"Communications "},{"Id":4,"Description":"CP","Name":"Contracts and Procurement "},{"Id":5,"Description":"PMD","Name":"Program Management Division "},{"Id":6,"Description":"RED","Name":"Research and Evaluation Division "},{"Id":7,"Description":"IT","Name":"Information Technology "}]
```

Here is attempt #2:

```
    function PopulateDivisions2()
{


    $.support.cors=true;


    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'http://IP/Service/api/DivisionSearch/GetAllDivisionsJsonP',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",

        success: function(data) {
                //data = JSON.parse(data):
                alert(data);

                $("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val("-99").html("Select One"));
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                $("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Name).html(item.Name));
            });
        },
        error: function(xhrequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            alert("PopulateDivisions2:  " + thrownError + " : " + ErrorText);
        }

    });

}
```

Error:  myJsonMethod was not called : parsererror

Here is the data Fiddler shows is coming back:

```
    "myJsonMethod([{\"Id\":1,\"Description\":\"Executive\",\"Name\":\"Executive \"},{\"Id\":2,\"Description\":\"ASD\",\"Name\":\"Administrative Services Division \"},{\"Id\":3,\"Description\":\"COM\",\"Name\":\"Communications \"},{\"Id\":4,\"Description\":\"CP\",\"Name\":\"Contracts and Procurement \"},{\"Id\":5,\"Description\":\"PMD\",\"Name\":\"Program Management Division \"},{\"Id\":6,\"Description\":\"RED\",\"Name\":\"Research and Evaluation Division \"},{\"Id\":7,\"Description\":\"IT\",\"Name\":\"Information Technology \"}]);"
```

Comment: are you receiving json or jsonp from your request ? You specified jsonp in the code but the title of the question tells "json", so the problem may be there...

Comment: I put the datatype as jsonp.  Json didn't bring anything back, it's cross domain, so jsonp worked.  I can see the data in fiddler, just can't get to success in ajax call.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` Tells your server that you are sending JSON data, but you don't have any data you are sending. Try leaving that setting out.

If you were to brows to your `url` in the browser do you get json back?

I'm not sure if this would matter, but I would remove the `error` setting because it says in the [jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that `This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests`.

I would try to run this with the least amount of configuration like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://IP/Service/api/DivisionSearch/GetAllDivisions',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

See if this works and then build on top of it. Without jsfiddle it's hard to debug what's going on.

Here is a link that should be a good resource for you: [Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5943630/1165441)

Comment: if I put the url in the browser I do get json back.

Comment: @user1202606 I've got nothing else besides to make sure that your function that wraps your ajax call is actually getting called. I know it seems trivial, but I'm at a loss of what to debug next.

Comment: I just edited my question above to show the data coming back in fiddler.  Can you notice anything with the data maybe?

Comment: @user1202606 I'm not sure, but it looks like it is returning the callback and I doubt that you want that. You just want the data. That is where your `jsonp: false` should come into play. Don't specify a `jsonpCallback`.

Comment: I can't believe that this important thing like $.ajax is so buggy? I try by days to solve this issue and can't understand why record is saved in remote DB but I got an error  "parsererror"!? :O Geez

Answer (score 0):

```
 function PopulateDivisions2(){
$.support.cors=true;
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'http://IP/Service/api/DivisionSearch/GetAllDivisionsJsonP?callback=?',
    data: {},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod" });


function myJsonMethod(data) {
            //data = JSON.parse(data):
            alert(data);$("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val("-99").html("Select One"));
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            $("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Name).html(item.Name));
        });
    }}
```

Can you try the above code? I have removed the success callback and included callback in query string.