# Sencha Proxy Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: extjs, proxy, sencha-touch

Trying to use sencha proxy - but no luck - I get the error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
    Ext.define('The.store.Login', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        config: {
            model: 'The.model.Login',
            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'THE_URL_THAT_RETURNS_JSON',
                headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'THE_AUTH_BASE64_ENCODED_KEY'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'd'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: false

        }
    });
```

This is my sencha code

And the json that comes back is -

```
    {
    "d" : [
    {
    "__metadata": {
    "uri": "States", "type": "State"
    }, "CountryCodeString": "USA", "StateCode": "AA", "ActiveFlag": true, "StateDescription": "Americas"
    }, {
    "__metadata": {
    "uri": "States", "type": "State"
    }, "CountryCodeString": "CAN", "StateCode": "AB", "ActiveFlag": true, "StateDescription": "Alberta"
    }, {
    "__metadata": {
    "uri": "States", "type": "State"
    }, "CountryCodeString": "BRA", "StateCode": "AC", "ActiveFlag": true, "StateDescription": "AC"
    }, {
    "__metadata": {
    "uri": "States", "type": "State"
    }, "CountryCodeString": "AUS", "StateCode": "ACT", "ActiveFlag": true, "StateDescription": "ACT"
    }, { .....
```

Comment: Just a guess, but did you verify that the json data coming back matches the model used by the store?

Comment: Yeah Model is good - Just that when I get the json I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `JsonP` then a callback is required from the server.  I.E.

`callback4587({"json":"here"})`

The `callback` will be sent as a parameter automatically by ExtJS framework and the server will need to respond with the same `callback`.

If you use `Ajax` request the `callback` will not be required.  However, you will need to setup cross origin access in server configuration.

Comment: I do not have access to teh server - all I can change is the Sencha code - What would you Suggest and Thanks a million for teh reply

Comment: I'm not positive there is a way around having the `callback` because it would be difficult to tell which response was for which request since JsonP uses `script tags` on `html element`.  Here is a link to a great [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp) of `JsonP` and `callback`

Comment: Is there any other alternate method - maybe ajax or rest - I can do anythign with the frontend - but dotn have access to server

Comment: You may be able to use `form.submit()` to a new page, i don't believe there would be access-origin constraints in that instance, however using `form.submit()` within an `iframe` would still cause issues in some browsers i believe.  `Ajax` will not work without proper setup on the server for access-origin.

Answer (score 1):

Change your proxy type to ajax.

Jsonp is required for retrieving data from a server in a different domain.