# jQuery $.ajax using local JSON data from global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to use `$.ajax` w/ JSON data (`window.jsonData = '{"dataCallback":[{"key":"val"}]})';`) stored in global variable inside the same local js document. Is this possible and if so how would I do it?

Update: It seems like `$.ajax()`, `$.getJSON()`, `$.get()`, `$.getScript()` all require url (which can point to a local or remote file) as the data source.

How can I use the global `window.jsonData` as the source of data?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Dns2r/. Feel free to play around.

Comment: If the `window.jsonData =` and `;` are included in the response, then it's a JavaScript response with an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) (what JSON got its syntax from). You should be able to request it with [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `$.getScript()` requires url as the data source. How can I make it accept the global variable `window.jsonData` as the data source?

Comment: Can you provide some context to show us why you need to do this? It may be that you are trying to solve a problem that would be better solved another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to mock an Ajax request and return local data instead. If that's the case, give [MockJax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) a whirl:

```
window.jsonData = '{"dataCallback":[{"key":"val"}]})';

// Set up the mockjax handler
$.mockjax({
  url: '/some/url',
  responseText: window.jsonData
});

// Now call the ajax method of your choice
$.getJSON('/some/url', function (data) {
  console.log(data.dataCallback[0].key); // "val"
});
```

Hope this is what you're after!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you've got to `eval` the responseText in the Ajax success callback, or use jQuery's built-in support for JSONP.

Another StackOverflow question that might help:

[Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: Right, how would I set that up? I'll throw up a jsfiddle for us to play with. Give me a few moments. Thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: Update: `eval(window.jsonData)` is throwing an error. Unfortunately, `$.ajax()` requires url as the data source. How can I make it accept the global variable `window.jsonData` as the data source?

Comment: The ajax response needs to be valid JavaScript that declares and populates that variable.