# unexpected token : from angular $http.jsonp request to Instagram API

Tags: json, angularjs, exception

I'm making a request to an authorized Instagram account to display images on a site. Originally, I was running into **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** when using Angular's `$http.get(...`.

From [Matt's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494083/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-for-instagram-like), It seems that I can use `getJSON`, or Angular `$http.jsonp`, to bypass this issue. [That Guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp) also says "JSONP is really a simply trick to overcome XMLHttpRequest same domain policy".

So, I'm no longer getting that problem, and am getting a json payload:

```
{"pagination":{"next_url":"https:\/\/api.instagram.com... etc
```

But am getting a very ambiguous error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

This is a response from the Instagram API, so I'm not sure why there'd be a syntax error on the inbound json. Also, It's hard to locate the error since the `jsonp` response is all on a single line... where the error is reported.

The preview shows that I'm getting a full payload:

[image]

Comment: it's not as simple as calling for jsonp if the API doesn't return jsonp. If api isn't CORS enabled or serving jsonp you need to use a proxy, either on your server or a third party service. Just because you see json payload, doesn't mean browser will allow access to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. Unfortunately there are no [JavaScript libraries](https://instagram.com/developer/libraries/) to help with this, but in the [Instagram API docs](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/), for JSONP you can wrap the response with a callback so that the json payload will be wrapped in `<script>` tags ([more info on jsonp here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)), therefore not blocked by Access Control Allow Origin.

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/coffee/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&callback=callbackFunction

Response:

```
callbackFunction({
    ...
});
```

So, in your http request URI, you add in a callback parameter. Since I am using Angular, their docs for `$http.jsonp()` requests specify the callback string as "[JSON_CALLBACK](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)".

So, my request URL for Angular would be:

```
$http.jsonp(
    'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/coffee/media/recent?
     access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
     .success(function(data) {...
```