# SVC Web service consuming from code behind but not from javascript

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, wcf, restful-architecture

I want to call web service in project (but in same solution) from myClient project.
I have added service reference in myClient project.
When I call scf from code behind it, works but when I try to call it from JavaScript using JSON, I am unable to do so. Guys pls help.

"http://someurl.com/MyWebService.svc/DoWork/" is path of my Service

abovive url someurl is url of localhost

This code is from a.aspx of client application of JSON,

```
 $.ajax(
                 {
                     type: 'GET',
                     url: 'http://someurl.com/MyWebService.svc/DoWork/',
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     data: "{}",
                     dataType: "json",
                     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert(errorThrown);
                         alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                     },
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert(data);
                     }

                 });
```

From Code behind

```
string postData = "http://someurl.com/MyWebService.svc/DoWork/";
            int timeout = 10;
            //string dwml = string.Empty;
            //MyServiceReference.MyWebServiceClient ms = new MyServiceReference.MyWebServiceClient();
            //dwml = ms.DoWork();
            //System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            //dwml = webClient.DownloadString(serviceURL);
            //Response.Write(dwml);

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(postData);
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            webRequest.Headers.Clear();
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            webRequest.Timeout = 1000 * timeout;
            webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application / x - www - form - urlencoded";
            webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
            webRequest.Timeout = 150000;
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.

            WebResponse webResponse = null;
            StreamReader objSR;
            System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            Stream objStream;
            string sResponse;

            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            objStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            objSR = new StreamReader(objStream, encode, true);
            //<<sResponse doesn't contain Unicode char values>>
            sResponse = objSR.ReadToEnd();
            Response.Write(sResponse);  // OR Response.write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sResponse))
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: please change your question to **how to consume WCF service from Javascript**, so that it will be quick searched by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys this immediate second question (both asked by me only) which only myself has answered or commented. I got ans 4 this from stack overflows old question
[Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Issue was with cross domain web-service call is not allowed through AJAX.
I came across new concept of JSONP, wow feeling great!

But I was expecting quick reply from Stack overflows other members.

I will not be able to rescue myself every time friends!

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp

Comment: Have you ever tried to call webservice from AJAX, getting JSON response?

Comment: plz recheck ur question, haven't mention anywhere that u require **cross domain** service call!

Comment: It is mentioned in my answer, because while asking question I was not knowing that issue was of cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

### calling WCF service from `RESTclient` in different solution without `JSONP`:

Here I came up with another working solution for, calling WCF service from `RESTclient` in different solution ***without using `JSONP`*** i.e. Enabling **CORS** of service (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) policy.
We all must have tried:

Adding Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in `web-config` file of Service Project,

**Code in web-config :**

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

but anyhow, that didn't worked out for me!

So, there is another way to achieve the same, is to *Create a `Global.asax`* in Service Project and Add this code to the `Global.asax.cs`:

**Code in Global.asax.cs :**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

And you can continue with your regular AJAX call from `RESTclient` solution to WCF service:

**Sample AJAX :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:51058/Service1.svc/GetData",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //do success part here
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
```

The best part is, no need to do any modifications in `RESTclient` project solution.

Answer (score 0):

here I have tried so far

### SVC code file `service1.svc.cs` :

```
using System;

namespace TestConnection
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", "Success");
        }
    }
}
```

### JavaScript function:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var text;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'Service1.svc/GetData', /*you .svc address : 'http://someurl.com/MyWebService.svc/DoWork/'*/
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (a) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(a);
                text = response.Table[0];
                alert(text);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Failure');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

All above code you might have tried, some important note to get this worked is:

**1.** as WCF .svc works on *Representational State Transfer* (REST), you have to explicitly mention data get request in `service1.svc` Markup file,

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet()]
//You can use below attributes to make necessary modifications
        //RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        //UriTemplate= "GetData"
        //)]
    string GetData();
```

To use `WebGet`,you will need to add library `System.ServiceModel.Web` to your service Project.

And if you have issues with basic settings then,

### Web.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMathService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

*NOTE:* This will not work for cross domain, if you want that, its answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798224/svc-web-service-consuming-from-code-behind-but-not-from-javascript/29119596#29119596).