# How to use Jsonp and ajax in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jsonp

I have one program that runs on a specific IP and put output in a file on same system.
I want to read that file from other system or domain(web) using ajax and jquery from jsp page.

I am getting error of cross browser origin not allowed.

To resolve this I am using jsonp as a datatype in ajax request.
But at server side do I need to handle callback parameter? how?

Comment: You need to handle callback parameter at server?? or at client?

Comment: I am unable to understand this callback.. where to handle it n how???

Comment: use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp

Comment: how to handle callback at server??