# PDF generation in mvc4 with itextsharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

I am working on pdf generation, it is successfully implemented  using itextsharp.dll. It’s working fine on local environment after publish also. We have our own server at other site

But same code doesn't work on the server,pdf is not generated instead it gives an error: *'The document has no pages.'*
    Initially I thought it is due to no data in document but it works locally with or without data in the document.

I had code implemented as follows to make a web request Is any problem in that ??

```
try
            {
                var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strPdfData + "?objpatId=" + patID);

                var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 900000;
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: can you post the code for pdf generation as well?.
Also where is the code located. As in same server or different server?

Comment: yup thanks for reply code is located on different server.Here is my code for it.will you please provide your email id so i can able to send attachment to you because here it is not possible to send you complete code due to more characters in it.

Comment: this might be any issue due to cross-domain interaction try to access some other method from the same server. Don't post your entire code just post the required snippets.

Comment: Hi Nikitesh I got following error -                                              A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Either the server u r trying to access is not accessible or the service you are calling might be throwing some exception.
Check the settings of server where the method is hosted.
This link might help you if you are making an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks nikitesh, I am making the call to the method like this  function callmethod(){window.location.href = "@Url.Action("generatePdf", "Admin")?patID=" +@user.PatientId +"&strPass=" + txtPassValue;}

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp

Comment: I have tried this one but when i go to download the pdf it doesn't show the dialogue box.    
          here is code which i did for download pdf.
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=EMRDetails.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

create a method in the controller:

```
     [HttpGet]
     public JsonResult GetFile()
     {
       var json = new WebClient().DownloadFile(string address, string fileName);
       //This code is just to convert the file to json you can keep it in file format and send to the view
       dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
       var oc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<countdata[]>(Convert.ToString(result.countdata));
       return Json(oc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

In the view just call this function:

```
@Url.Action('genPDF','GetFile');
```