# How to use multiple values with jQuery ajax dataType?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I should request the data as `jsonp` to perform cross domain request. But actual result returned is json like `{"q":"iphone","r":["iphone 5","iphone","обмен на iphone","iphone 4","iphone 5s"]}`.

I've tried to use multiple values in [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp json',
  jsonp: false,
  ...
```

but it returns `parsererror` (the same as just with `jsonp`).

I also tried to do the call with and without `callback`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp json',
  cache: true,
  jsonpCallback: 'callbackFunctionName',
  jsonp: 'callback',
```

What can I do to process such result correctly?

Upd. I tried to use `script` instead of `jsonp`, it works better - `success`/`done` function is called (instead of `error`/`fail`), but I can not get response text - data passed to `success()` is `undefined` as well as `jqXHR.responseText` passed to `complete()` is empty.

Comment: Does your URL contain a callback function?

Comment: Have you stumbled upon this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp#answer-14523763 ?

Comment: @sri, I've tried both with and without callback function.

Comment: @sri, how `getJSON` can help here? If I would pass it with `?` at the end, believe, it will expect jsonp response as well.

Comment: I think that was just another way of using a `callback`. But as you said you tried both with and without callback, it won't be useful!

Comment: May be why not edit the question with only callback you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple *dataTypes*, if you use JSONP this will return a JSONP block which you could use to call a callback to handle the return data like this:

- [Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

You want to return a response formed as a JSONP block which would be something like:

```
callback({
    "q": "iphone",
    "r": ["iphone 5", "iphone", "обмен на iphone", "iphone 4", "iphone 5s"]
});
```

From here you can use the *callback* assuming that you are using the AJAX call with the set *callback* parameter.

Comment: Can not I use it with `script` as well? If I use `script` instead of `jsonp`, then `success` function is called (instead of `error`), but I can not get response text - `data` passed to `success()` is undefined as well as `jqXHR.responseText` passed to `complete()` is empty.

Comment: The main problem with my case - server returns pure `json`, not `jsonp` block. So the example given in the linked question also doesn't work.

Comment: You have to form the response as a jsonp block otherwise you will get a string formed as json but which is expected to be a jsonp-block.

Comment: This is 3rd party server, so I can not change the response.

Comment: Then you can't use JSONP, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return multiple datatypes from the URL then there is no need to pass the `dataType` in jQuery AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        //dataType: "json",  comment this line
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {},
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {}
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in an earlier post, you can remove the dataType attribute completely. In which case, JQuery Ajax will intelligently guess the output and do the conversion.

*https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - dataType*

> make sure that response header – “Content-Type” is text/plain and mimeType is not explicitly provided as part of AJAX options.

**ajaxHandleResponses** - will automatically try to detect the conversion type based on mimeType and Content-Type header.

```
function ajaxHandleResponses( s, jqXHR, responses ) {

var ct, type, finalDataType, firstDataType,
    contents = s.contents,
    dataTypes = s.dataTypes;

// Remove auto dataType and get content-type in the process
while ( dataTypes[ 0 ] === "*" ) {
    dataTypes.shift();
    if ( ct === undefined ) {
        ct = s.mimeType || jqXHR.getResponseHeader( "Content-Type" );
    }
}
```

**Another solution is to use custom conversion**

Do AJAX custom conversion based on response either to JSON or retain as String if the response is not JSON.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
            return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceURL,
                converters: {
                    'text mycustomtype': (result) => {
                        return this.getResponse(result);
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'mycustomtype'
            });

        this.getResponse = (result) => {
            let response;
            try {
                response = JSON.parse(result);
            }
            catch (e) {
                response = result;
            }
            return response;
        };
```