# Handle ajax response that accept text and json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Say I submit a form via Ajax and receiving a response from the servlet either in text or json so is there any way to handle both responses. As I have gone through this jquery/ajax documentation [Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and there I found the `accept` and `converter` to deal with it but after trying it I didn't get any expected result.So can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple values with jQuery ajax dataType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684026/how-to-use-multiple-values-with-jquery-ajax-datatype)

Comment: @Zenoo I think only problem subject are matching but the content is totally different.Because in my case I am getting data from servlet either in string or json

Comment: Meaning you're receiving different `datatypes`. Which is what the duplicate is about.

Comment: @Zenoo I had gone through the solution of your given question and there they had given 'JSONP' to handle with different responses but I have found the solution without using JSONP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my case, I have handled the different responses in javascript via ajax  without using JSONP AND dataType

Here is my solution

```
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),

    url: form.attr('action'),

    data: form.serialize(),

    error: function(theRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
        alert(theRequest.responseText);
        alert(errorThrown);

    },

    success: function(data) {

        alert('sucess');

        var result = data; // it may be string or json

        alert(result);

        if (result == 'error') { // if it is String
            // do your stuff
        } else { // if it is json

            // convert in json
            var jsondata = JSON.parse(result);
            alert(jsondata);
            // after converting it do your stuff
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see that I have handled different responses at different places according to usage.But there is a condition that

> In javascript, almost everything is an object. But these objects are
>   bit different from what we see in Java, C++ or other conventional
>   languages. An object in JS is simply a hashmap with key-value pairs. A
>   key is always a string, and a value can be anything including strings,
>   integers, booleans, functions, other objects etc