# How can I make Ajax request to a URL beginning with no-http scheme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want my page to do requests to a special app (named QuickBooks web connector) on local comp.

Like this:
qbwc://docontrol/WSExists?AppName=WCWebService

I have this function:

```js
function CheckQWCLoaded() 
{
    var strURL = 'qbwc://docontrol/WSExists?AppName=Quickbooks+to+eUnify+Integration';
    var CheckResult = false;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: strURL,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (XMLHTTP) 
        { 
            // Response should be a string True/False
            // if (XMLHTTP.status == 200) CheckResult = jQuery.parseJSON(XMLHTTP.responseText);
        }
    });
    return CheckResult;
}
```

When I run it in IE: I get something like 'Access denied', Chrome returns some different error.
I understand that it is related to cross domain and scheme restrictions, just want to know if it is possible to do it or should I create a small (.net) windows app instead of running it from web page.

Comment: Does the service implement [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)? If not, you will probably have to write a proxy to get around that limitation.

Comment: Did u try jsonp request? [stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: Its a browser plugin that handles qbwc: right? I doubt Javascript in the browser sandbox is allowed to see that. Plus this might not even be HTTP, or anything like it, its just not doable without some kind of external http service that can translate to qbwc. Or I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read docs fully. It is an "asynchronous
pluggable protocol handler", working under IE.

Comment: I really doubt JS can work with it. Or I could send you to a page I control with some JS that went to `qbwc:/transfer/$1000/SlavaTT/to/Spacedman` (hypothetical example). Giving JS access to browser plugin schemes is opening a whole world of pain, bugs, security exploits and system holes. So yeah IE probably does let you do it.

Comment: ok,thanks, will be reading more on it