# parse error in query ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Calling a webservice written in php and ajax call is ending up in error function

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert('ajax');
                $.ajax({ 
                               type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                   // crossDomain: true,
                     contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "http://domain/Customer/getCountryList",
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET"
                   },
                   success: function(data){   
                       alert("In S"); 
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,statusText){
                    alert("In N");

                  alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
                   }
                })
            })

        </script>
```

And teh service file output is

```
[{"responseCode":"0"},
[{"countryId":"1","countryName":"USA","isdCode":"","isActive":"\u0001"}]]
```

how to parse this out put

Comment: this is not enough to understand the problem.. Plz provide more info

Comment: you can use $.parseJSON(data); for parsing the json data.

Comment: it seems its already json you can access country just like this example http://jsfiddle.net/jq5vLc7u/

Comment: are you trying to access cross domain or using same server?

Answer (score 0):

**First:** this is response header not request header, you can send request header only from `$.ajax()`

```
headers: {
       Accept: "application/json",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET"
}
```

### Parse error:

You are trying to access other domain using ajax but while web server won't provide above header until you can't access response using AJAX, this is called `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`

> Reason Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at web server. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

You can also access another server response if server provide `JSONP` callback method, see more detail [**`click here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET" specified the above two lines in the service file also CORS is enabled,but still the same error is showing up

Comment: then no need to pass these header in ajax request header these response headers

Comment: so your issue on response `error: function()` calling?

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is working fine
`dataType: "json"` means you parse incoming data to json.

However you json data is invalid due to `"\u0001"` string.

So remove `dataType: "json"` and replace

```
data = data.replace("\u0001", "\\\\u0001")
```

and then parse to json.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z2txchng/)