# Cross domain ajax with jsonP and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, jsonp

i have been battling with cross domain referencing for days now , i have implemented some examples targeted at public API's that i came across on stack overflow : [Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp) and try to mix it up to work for me but to no avail , my code works on my local host but not on a remote server and here it is

javascript :

```
function load_data()
{ var data_output = $('#data_output');

$.getJSON("http://localhost/my_CI_root/index/load_data/News/?callback=?", function(response) {
   $.each(response, function(i, item){
     var landmark = ' <p class="column-responsive half-bottom">'
            + '<img src="http://www.bytepixels.com.ng/decoy/main/report/'+ item.media  +'" alt="img">'
            + '<strong>' + item.subject + '</strong>'
            + '<em>'+ item.message + '</em>'
            + '</p><div class="decoration"></div>';

            console.log(response);
            data_output.append(landmark);
   });
});



 }
```

and my codeigniter function:

```
  function load_data($value)
  {
  header('Content-type: application/json');

  $results = $this->my_model->load_data($value); 

  echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($results) . ')';
  }
```

like i said it works on localhost , im aware of the cross domain constraint and from what i read , $.getJson() is suppose to solve this issue but when i point my URL to http://www.xxxx.com/index/load_data/News/?callback=? it gives me an error 404 , ive tried enabling query strings on Codeigniter but it didnt help , any help would be aprreciated . thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the URL the filename should be index.php instead of index.

404 error means you have got the wrong URL.