# How to Bypass Cross Orginin (CORS) by JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xml

my project is needed to **bypass CORS**. And i believe in **JSONP** can do it. I want to **Load XML from another domain** with **JSONP**. I need to help in this problem.

And this is my idea:

- **Step 1**: Connected to another domain by JSONP (with username and password)
- **Step 2**: Because **XML construction is different from JSONP**, so, in step 2, i want to **convert data before GET**, and i want to **convert data to TEXT**.
- **Step 3:** Convert **TEXT DATA** to **XML DATA**.
- **Step 4:** Do something with XML Data.

I think AJAX Jquery datatype ="JSONP TEXT XML" can do it. But in my project. I can't do it.

Thanks for helping !!!

Comment: You can only use JSONP if the receiving domain supports it. If it doesn't there is nothing you can do client side, other than use a server-side proxy.

Comment: Yeah, my domain is support JSONP. But i don't know how to use it with GET

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp

Comment: It's working good with basic protected site and GET @RoryMcCrossan ? Thanks !