# Cookie returns null in web api

Tags: javascript, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I am using cookie for the authentication in web api. Creating cookies in the server side web api. and when i am  reading it shows me null.
   also, i am sending a request using html ajax.

Function using to create cookie:

```
public HttpResponseMessage SetCookies()
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()`enter code here`;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("MyCookie", "12345");
        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookie.Path = "/";

        resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
        return resp;
    }
```

after creating the cookies i try to reading cookie using below code:

```
 CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("MyCookie").FirstOrDefault();
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                string sessionId = cookie["MyCookie"].Value;
            }
```

it always returns null.

Please help me how to get and set the cookie value.

Thank you.

Here is the java script code :

```
function setCookie() {
    var cname = " MyCookie";
    var cvalue = "1234fer5678";
    var exdays = 1;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function onButtonClick() {
    setCookie();`enter code here`
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:49702/v1/user/register',
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true
    });      

};
```

I set the cookies value manually. still i get the cookies in header request null on the server side api

Comment: Can you put your javascript code here?I think it is passable some problem with js.

Comment: added java script code @gangzi

Answer (score 0):

I had seen your javascript code, and in the code `crossDomain: true`, I think your problem is about the `cross domain`, you can try this :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:49702/v1/user/register',
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! jsonp (lowercase)
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true
    });
```

update: look the code blow , you can set the `domain` when you set cookie.

```
var cookieName = 'HelloWorld';
var cookieValue = 'HelloWorld';
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate 
                  + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";
```

Comment: I tried the above code and tried with cross domain true and false both but it doesnt working gives same null record.

Comment: you can read this link,if then [basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: set the cookie as you said but no luck. still shows cookies null.

Comment: When i try to get the cookie in simple controller like the below code i am able to get the cookies but when i try to get the cookies in api controllers i get the cookies null

Comment: protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("MyCookie"))
            {
                Session["MyCookie"] = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }