# GET works when URL copied into address bar, but not via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a series of endpoints that a vendor's application has open for me to get files from. If I enter these endpoints into the address bar of a browser, the file opens up, but if I try to GET them via jQuery AJAX, it fails with a cross-origin error (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain' is therefore not allowed access.). The vendor application REST Web service does not support CORS. Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://vendorrestwebservice/endpoint",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
    console.log("downloaded file");
  },
  error: function (error) {
    console.log("Failed to download file!");
  }
});
```

Why does the file open when pasted into an address bar, but not when called via my GET request?

Comment: Well if vendor WS doesn't have CORS enabled then I think you're out of luck. Maybe try processing WS on the server-side.

Comment: Does the vendor's REST web service support AJAX-P requests? Oftentimes, these are used as a CORS-free workaround, if provided. If not, then there's not really anything you can do.

Comment: No such luck, as they don't support jsonp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API needs to allow your domain to access it via ajax(from another domain).

When accessing directly from a browser, you are on the correct domain... :)

You can try to proxy the ajax call like this:

Make a ajax call to your server -> your server calls the api and then returns the data

OR you could try to user JSONP.
[Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: That makes sense. Any work arounds since they refuse to allow CORS?

Comment: @Kode yes, search is magical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain . Or just make a script on your end and make a curl request to the other site.

Comment: No jsonp support either. Very limiting API