# AngularJS (and Ionic) Issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to AngularJS and Ionic, and am trying to get json data into a page but I can't seem to get it to work.

In my app.js, I have this:

```
(function() {

 var app = angular.module('myreddit', ['ionic', 'angularMoment','LocalStorageModule']);

   app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url : '/',
            templateUrl : 'index.html',
            controller : 'MainController'
        });
          $stateProvider.state('posts', {
          url: '/posts',
          templateUrl: 'templates/posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    });

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});


}());
```

And then I have a file called WPCtrl.js, which is:

```
angular.module('myreddit') {

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout,     $sce, DataLoader, $rootScope ) {

  // Enter your site url here. You must have the WP-API v2     installed on this site. Leave /wp-json/wp/v2/ at the end.
  $rootScope.url = 'http://scottbolinger.com/wp-json/wp/v2/';

  $rootScope.callback = '_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

})

.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,     DataLoader, $ionicLoading, $rootScope, $sce, CacheFactory, $log,     Bookmark, $timeout ) {

  if ( ! CacheFactory.get('postCache') ) {
    CacheFactory.createCache('postCache');
  }

  var postCache = CacheFactory.get( 'postCache' );

  $scope.itemID = $stateParams.postId;

  var singlePostApi = $rootScope.url + 'posts/' + $scope.itemID +     '?_embed&' + $rootScope.callback;

  $scope.loadPost = function() {

    // Fetch remote post

    $ionicLoading.show({
      noBackdrop: true
    });

    DataLoader.get( singlePostApi ).then(function(response) {
      $scope.post = response.data;

      // Don't strip post html
      $scope.content =     $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.content.rendered);

      $scope.comments = $scope.post._embedded['replies'][0];

      // add post to our cache
      postCache.put( response.data.id, response.data );

      $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(response) {
      $log.error('error', response);
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

  }

  if( !postCache.get( $scope.itemID ) ) {

    // Item is not in cache, go get it
    $scope.loadPost();

  } else {
    // Item exists, use cached item
    $scope.post = postCache.get( $scope.itemID );
    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(     $scope.post.content.rendered );
    $scope.comments = $scope.post._embedded['replies'][0];
  }

  // Bookmarking
  $scope.bookmarked = Bookmark.check( $scope.itemID );

  $scope.bookmarkItem = function( id ) {

    if( $scope.bookmarked ) {
      Bookmark.remove( id );
      $scope.bookmarked = false;
    } else {
      Bookmark.set( id );
      $scope.bookmarked = true;
    }
  }

  // Pull to refresh
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {

    $timeout( function() {

      $scope.loadPost();

      //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

    }, 1000);

  };

})

.controller('PostsCtrl', function( $scope, $http, DataLoader,     $timeout, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $rootScope, $log ) {

  var postsApi = $rootScope.url + 'posts?' + $rootScope.callback;

  $scope.moreItems = false;

  $scope.loadPosts = function() {

    // Get all of our posts
    DataLoader.get( postsApi ).then(function(response) {

      $scope.posts = response.data;

      $scope.moreItems = true;

      //$log.log(response.data);

     }, function(response) {
      $log.error(response);
    });

  }

  // Load posts on page load
  $scope.loadPosts();

  paged = 2;

  // Load more (infinite scroll)
  $scope.loadMore = function() {

    if( !$scope.moreItems ) {
      return;
    }

    var pg = paged++;

    $log.log('loadMore ' + pg );

    $timeout(function() {

      DataLoader.get( postsApi + '&page=' + pg     ).then(function(response) {

        angular.forEach( response.data, function( value, key ) {
          $scope.posts.push(value);
        });

        if( response.data.length <= 0 ) {
          $scope.moreItems = false;
        }
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.moreItems = false;
        $log.error(response);
      });

      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');

    }, 1000);

  }

  $scope.moreDataExists = function() {
    return $scope.moreItems;
  }

  // Pull to refresh
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {

    $timeout( function() {

      $scope.loadPosts();

      //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

    }, 1000);

  };

})

 .controller('BookmarksCtrl', function( $scope, $http,     DataLoader, $timeout, $rootScope, $log, Bookmark, CacheFactory ) {

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {

    if ( ! CacheFactory.get('postCache') ) {
      CacheFactory.createCache('postCache');
    }

    var postCache = CacheFactory.get( 'postCache' );

    if ( ! CacheFactory.get('bookmarkCache') ) {
      CacheFactory.createCache('bookmarkCache');
    }

    var bookmarkCacheKeys = CacheFactory.get( 'bookmarkCache'     ).keys();

    $scope.posts = [];

    angular.forEach( bookmarkCacheKeys, function( value, key ) {
      var newPost = postCache.get( value );
      $scope.posts.push( newPost );
    });

  });  
})
});
});
```

Any ideas why it's not displaying?

Comment: What is the error? Show me your console log.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:35730/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".

Loading FeedCtrl
SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PostsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=PostsCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: at ionic.bundle.js:8900
    at assertArg (ionic.bundle.js:10602)
    at assertArgFn (ionic.bundle.js:10612)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17807
    at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:52338)
    at Object.switcher.render (ionic.bundle.js:50456)
    at Object.switcher.init (ionic.bundle.js:50376)
    at self.render (ionic.bundle.js:52198)
    at self.register (ionic.bundle.js:52156)
    at updateView (ionic.bundle.js:57577)

Comment: It looks like it's related to `JSONP` request. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp) could help you.