# Synchronous Jquery Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to ensure that "Test Data" text get displayed in the console only after books details are loaded in vm.books, basically want to perform synchronous ajax call.

Below mention code is not working as expected. any suggestion how to achieve this expected functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vm = new obj.Books();
  vm.loadBooks();
  console.log("Test Data");
});

var obj = obj || {};
obj.Books = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.books = [];

  self.loadBooks = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "somewebapiurl",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(idx, item) {
          self.books.push(item);

        });
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp

Comment: any suggestion how to achieve the expected functionality.

Comment: Definitely don't block the thread. Bad perf and bad UX... and bad JavaScript. Use callbacks or the better option is to use jQuery's ajax deferred object.

Comment: Do you want to make the request synchronous, or do you want to solve your problem? Because a synchronous call is the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: @juhana just want to find the solution to this requirement, ideally we can pass the success and error callback for loadBooks function.

Answer (score 1):

> How to ensure that "Test Data" text get displayed in the console only
>   after books details are loaded in vm.books, basically want to perform
>   synchronous ajax call.

Just leverage the jQuery Deferred Object's [`.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) function.

```
self.loadBooks = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "somewebapiurl",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(idx, item) {
      self.books.push(item);

    });
    //do what you want or call the function you want
    console.log("Test Data");
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(status);
  });
};
```

Comment: Many thanks for the edit, i have to improve my answers

Comment: We cannot modify the  self.loadBooks function, responsibility of the loadBooks is to load the self.books array.  We have to just invoke loadBooks and expect books array to have values in it and then display the text and work with books array i.e we can display the list of books in the array.

Comment: @sameer you can return ajax promise from loadBooks and then use `vm.loadBooks().done(function() { console.log("Test Data"); });`

Answer (score 0):

@jcubic was right , jsonp does not support synchronous call with async=false.

Therefore,

- Enabled the CORS in Service side (i.e. somewebapiurl)
- Set origin details (i.e. origins="http://localhost:19410" headers="*"
  methods="get" )
- Removed the datatype='jsonp'
- Retained async=false

Now it is working  as expected.