# Get data from third party Node.js server hosted on Vagrant VM using jQuery - JSONP

Tags: jquery, node.js, vagrant, jsonp

I've got a Node.js server listening on localhost:3000 **working as a black box** that **outputs UI** that I want to load into a local website.

The **consuming service** written in jQuery is:

```
$('.my_selector').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: ':3000/',
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#content").append(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of visiting the page directly it loads content and appends it to `#content`.

**The issue** is that the code does not work.

---

**Edit:**

If I set `localhost:3000` to `url` I get `XMLHttpRequest Exception`:

```
jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource
```

Comment: so what's the point? hope that `url: ':3000/'` contain the full absolute url of the node server. If you GET a page why you `method: "POST"` code?

Comment: @morels If I use localhost:3000, I get the following error, `jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`
But without it seems to work
I copied the sample from another answer here

Comment: right. you need to use [JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) please see this solution [Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: Change your url to just '/', if your page is already on localhost:3000.

Comment: @morels isn't JSONP for different domains? They are both on localhost. Although that did work thanks!

Comment: @milky_jay answered below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [use JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp) to overcome the Cross origin issue. Although both the Node server and your custom visiting webpage are on localhost, please note that there is a huge difference on configuration:

- your custom visiting webpage is **fully hosted** on local LAMP stack*.
- Node is only **proxy/reverse-proxy configured** locally (thanks to Vagrant automation) !

The real (virtual)IP of the Node server is the one configured on the vagrant VM, you can check it using `ifconfig` after [opening a ssh session](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/up.html) towards the VM. This way the HTTP response received from the page hosted locally has a different IP and domain in the header and the Cross origin exception is triggered.

*= supposing for example you are running a LAMP system.

Answer (score 1):

Use url: "/"
the default host name use is current in url window.location.host in your case localhost:3000. Just specify / for path

Answer (score 0):

Change `url: ':3000/'`, to `url : "http://127.0.0.1:3000"`.

Answer (score 0):

3 things you need to do:

1. `url: ':3000/'` is incorrect, you need to change it to `url: 'localhost:3000'`
2. You need to put your HTML, javascript, css, ... files **on a web server (such as apache, nginx, ..)** which is running on your localhost (e.g: `localhost:4000`). **Don't open the HTML file by right clicking then choose open with Chrome or thing like that, it won't work**. And access the page which contain that javascript file (e.g: `localhost:4000/page-contain-your-javascript.html`)
3. Deal with cross domain issue:

   Use a reverse proxy such as [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) to dispatch request to `localhost:3000/page-contain-your-javascript.html` to `localhost:4000/page-contain-your-javascript.html`. And now, when you access `localhost:3000/page-contain-your-javascript.html` your javascript and API now **in the same domain (localhost:3000)**, you can use AJAX normally.

Hope that it can help you :)