# Get cross domain data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to get cross domain data.

Due to browser security restrictions, most Ajax requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol [(Details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax) .

So i am using YQL https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery--net-10225 to get html data.

My question is how to make call using external proxy server. For example `https://www.pinterest.com/` , so i am using external proxy server with direct url access like `https://www.filterbypass.me/s.php?k=https://www.pinterest.com/` .

But the problem is yql query return to null, no response data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="https://www.filterbypass.me/s.php?k=https://www.pinterest.com/"') + '&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=',
    dataType: 'json' ,
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

Comment: `b=1&f=norefer` - these are URL search parameters for `jetproxy` - was that your intent?

Comment: No. I remove that but still not working. @JaromandaX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: _“some website are blocked in my country”_ – and how is that an issue? Does YQL make the request to the site “from” your country? I rather doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use `JSONP` you can use `getJSON` which made for that. jQuery has helper methods for `JSONP`

```
$.getJSON( 'http://someotherdomain.com/service.php', function( result ) {
       console.log(result);
});
```

Read the below links

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

[Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)