# Laravel 5 jquery getJSON not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel-5, csrf

I am trying to get JSON data from API on Laravel 5 , The route gives me correct
Data in the browser but when trying to access this route in JQuery it failed.
the route is:
http://localhost:8000/search/student/all

worked finally in the browser and the data is displayed in json format
but this script failed:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/search/student/all", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I replaced localhost:8000 with 127.0.0.1:8000 but nothing changed.

Note: I generated the json response using Laravel

```
$students=App\Student::all();
return response()->json($students);
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can do like something below

```
$.get( "http://localhost:8000/search/student/all", function(data ) {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  console.log(obj);
});
```

> Another possibility use jsonp

JSONP is really a simply trick to overcome XMLHttpRequest same domain policy. (As you know one cannot send AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) request to a different domain.)

```
$.ajax({
     url:"http://localhost:8000/search/student/all",
     dataType: 'jsonp', 
     success:function(data){
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(obj)
     },
     error:function(){

     }      
});
```

[Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: thanks but the problem is still the same working fine on browser but in jquery no results retrieved.

Comment: ok the log give me this error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/search/student/all(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: you can accept it as correct answer , if it helped you . This is how stack overflow works :)

Comment: @sumit the `toJson` isn't necessary when passing a collection to be printed as a JSON response. What OP had for their PHP code is fine.

Comment: Yea , his problem was related to "CORS header" . I have already edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/search/student/all", function(result){
        $.each(result.students, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(field.name + " ");//name is database field name such as id,name,address etc
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
$students=App\Student::all();
echo json_encode($students);//or return $students->toJson();
```