# How to use JSONP on fetch/axios cross-site requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, fetch, axios

I'm trying to do a GET request on wikipedia API. Using jQuery as below works fine:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=Test&callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log("Data: ", data);  
});
```

But I want to use fetch or axios api, which stops at **pre-flight** with request method: **OPTIONS**. Why it works in jQuery but not in the other APIs?

```
axios.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=Test&callback=JSON_CALLBACK', 
    { headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'content-type': 'text/plain'}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Response: ", response);  
    });
```

I saw that it might be related to the Content-Type of the GET request, on jQuery the default seems to be **text/plain**, however I didn't have success when trying to alter the content-type of fetch/axios requests which are being sent as **text/html**.

Any thoughts on what might be the problem?

Comment: I don't think axios supports jsonp.

Comment: you are right, I'll take that off

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found that the problem is not related to the content-type of the requests.

The problem was due to the fact that the APIs (fetch and axios) does not support **jsonp** requests. The use of **jsonp** was not clear enough for me, I could find a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6879276/4051961

Although they don't support it, they offers alternatives to perform **jsonp** requests:

axios: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md#jsonp

fetch: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-jsonp

Answer (score 14):

Recommended way to access JSONP with axios is actually to not use axios:

1. [The Discussion on Why (not)](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/15)
2. [A similar question](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/75#issuecomment-113329017)
3. [Alternative Suggestion from Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md#jsonp)

**In short install:**

```
npm install jsonp --save
```

**use it like:**

```
var jsonp = require('jsonp');

jsonp('http://www.example.com/foo', null, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**Ran into the problem in a React Application**

Axios doesn't support JSONP they offers alternatives to perform jsonp requests:

Follow this link to see some documentation for jsonp for axios:
axios: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md#jsonp

Here is my documentation:

Step 1: `$ npm install jsonp --save`

Step 2:

```js
import jsonp from 'jsonp';
```

(this goes at the top of your component)

Step 3: Create a method in your React Component:

```js
JSONP () {
        jsonp( "https://*YourUrlHere.jsonp", { name: 'Name Of JSONP Callback Function' }, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                this.setState({
                    error,
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    data: data,
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-jsonp will also work fro react and its very simple.

Answer (score 2):

`yarn add simple-jsonp-promise` or `npm install simple-jsonp-promise`

```
import jsonp from 'simple-jsonp-promise'

async function Test () {
  const url = 'http://...'
  const params = {param1: 1, param2: 2}

  const response = await jsonp(url, {data: params})
  console.log('response:', response)
}
```