# PHP Ajax Post File and Text Same Time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can post only image and get it with $_FILES['foto']['name']. I need post image and text same time.

```
        var fotoFile = new FormData();
        $('#foto').on('change', function (evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                fotoFile.append("foto", files[0]);
            }
        });
```

It is post code

```
`                $.ajax({
                    url: 'postpages/personelsave.php', 
                    dataType: 'text',
                    type: 'post',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: {foto : fotoFile, tc_no : document.getElementById('tcNo').value},                         
                    success: function(php_script_response){
                        alert(php_script_response);
                    }
                });`
```

and personelsave.php

```
$_FILES['foto']['type']
$_POST["tc_no"]
```

Error : undefined index foto.

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `multiple dataTypes`, if you use JSONP this will return a jsonp block which you could use to call a callback to handle the return data like this:

[Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

So through JSONP you can handle multiple dataTypes.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below to submit all types of input data including file

```
var formData = new FormData($("#formID")[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'postpages/personelsave.php', 
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
});
```