# JSONP not working on json converted url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

The answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp#answer-14523763) question relating to JSONP does work as of. If there is a `?` at the end of a url during `.getJSON` request it recognizes as a  JSONP.

However in my case it is not working. 
I have a url lets say `(sanjokgrg.com/aboutme)`which displays the whatever data queried from the about table, I also added an extra feature where it looks for `json=true` in the URL which converts the result into `json` this way `print json_encode($data);` in php. So `sanjokgrg.com/aboutme` displays the normal data while `sanjokgrg.com/aboutme?json=true` displays the json data but `getJson` does not recognize `sanjokgrg.com/aboutme?json=true` and I tried a placeholder api `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments` and it works only my `?json=true` not working

Comment: that website doesnt exist, or is that just an example?

Comment: I was only using it to explain the question. I added "lets say" in my question.

Comment: JSON and JSONP are not the same thing. The server has to be able to generate JSONP, not JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling Please Look at the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ says it being a JSONP when ? is attached at the end

Comment: I understand. But then the server has to send JSON**P** back, *not* JSON. If the server does not support JSON**P** you cannot *request* JSON**P**. You are saying *" I also added an extra feature where it looks for json=true in the URL which converts the result into json"* to me sounds like you are not sending JSONP back. However, before you go through the trouble to add JSONP support to the server: Do you need JSONP support in the first place?

Comment: @FlexKling It works when Im using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments external JSON url. DOes that mean I have to take into account for a JSONP somehow with my PHP ??

Comment: You should have a look at the actual request and response that is sent to the example server. jQuery will actually request something like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?callback=someCallback . As you can see the result is not JSON. Maybe have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP to learn more about how JSONP works and whether you actually need it. *"DOes that mean I have to take into account for a JSONP somehow with my PHP"* Yes.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. I made it work, have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. Thanks to @Felix Kling for some insight regarding JSONP. Looks like I should have looked more into understanding the concept of JSONP. 
While it is true that adding a `?` at the end of the `.getJson` request makes the request a JSONP, that does not necessarily mean the server will comply to that request. So the server needs to account for the "padding". I had php source code to my server so I was able to amend the output by doing this.

`echo header('Content-Type: application/json');`

`echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['callback'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."(".json_encode($data).");";`

On hindsight should have been more of a php question.