# Kendo Scheduler DataSource parsererror being thrown

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, scheduler

When I try to bind this Remote JSON array

```
[{"id":1,
  "title":"Test 1",
  "description":null,
  "start":"2018-07-13T00:00:00",
  "end":"2018-07-13T01:00:00",
  "startTimezone":null,
  "endTimezone":null,
  "recurrenceId":null,
  "recurrenceRule":null,
  "recurrenceException":null,
  "isAllDay":false},
 {"id":2,
  "title":"Test 2",
  "description":null,
  "start":"2018-07-13T03:00:00",
  "end":"2018-07-13T04:00:00",
  "startTimezone":null,
  "endTimezone":null,
  "recurrenceId":null,
  "recurrenceRule":null,
  "recurrenceException":null,
  "isAllDay":false}
]
```

via

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
    transport: {
           read: {
                    url: "https://localhost:44346/api/xxxxx",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { 
                        console.log(textStatus, "read") 
                    }      
                },
            }
    });
```

textStatus results in 'parsererror'

Any suggestions/help welcome!

Thanks
Alan Painter

Answer (score 1):

`JSONP` is used when the server will deliver `json` data in the form *callback_function*(*the-json*).  This feature is used when the server will be delivering information to requests from clients referring from a different server.  Without using JSONP those types of requests will get an error.

See

- [SO: Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)
- [jQuery.ajax doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If your server is returning json data directly to a page already being served by it, try `datatype:'json'`.  The lack of a `jsonp` value being sent back indicates the service routine is not examining or honoring the inbound `dataType` specified.