# Jquery callback not working inside done success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

On posting to server: i got jsonp({"code":"680","country":"UK","status":"Citizen"}); i.e the content of result and am trying to access the value of country.

My attempt was creating my own jsonp function to access it.

```
done(function (result, status, xhr){

   console.log(result); 

    //log result is: 

    //jsonp({"code":"680","country":"UK","status":"Citizen"});
     transfer(result);
})

//outside of jquery call; i have this outside the click function.
function transfer(result){
   var xyz = result;
   function jsonp(xyz){
     alert(xyz.country);
   } 
 }
```

I don`t get to access the county in jquery done function.;
In a nuetral script this works i.e creating and html file for testing.

```
<script>
 var result = jsonp({"code":"680","country":"UK","status":"Citizen"});

  jsonp(result){
      alert(result.country);          // alert is UK
      console.log(result.country);   //result is UK.
  }
  </script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I do not clearly understand your goal, where is called function jsonp?

Comment: I think the result is a string that comes from the response of a server.  So, you need to use eval or exec to call the function.

Comment: If you're receiving a JSONP formatted response you need to set the `dataType` in the `$.ajax()` call to `'jsonp'`. jQuery will then deserialise the object for you, completely avoiding the problem you have right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: @Plastic, what i meant was after the return from the server: jsonp({"code":"680","country":"UK","status":"Citizen"}); i want to have the access to the country. i.e UK. inside of done success. Looking at the response returned, i created a function jsonp(obj){ console.log(obj.country); }. In all nothing happened, no console, no warning. Thank you.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, i did set the dataType to jsonp.

Comment: @Haji then please show all of your relevant code so we can fully understand what you're going

Comment: }).done(function (result, status, xhr) {
                                var tya = result;
                                console.log("Doing");
                                function jsonp(xyz){
                                    alert(xyz.country);
                                }
                                console.log("Done");  The alert function returns nothing, but i got console for Doing and Done.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this.

```js
    done(function (result, status, xhr){

       console.log(result); 

       //log result is: 

       //jsonp({"code":"680","country":"UK","status":"Citizen"});
       eval(result);
    })



    function jsonp(xyz){
      alert(xyz.country);
    }
```

Comment: `eval` is almost never the correct answer. It is never the correct answer to use against code retrieved from a service.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I would encourage you to help with the correct answer, in this way everyone would know the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure he, and lots of others, would if the OP had provided enough information in the question to provide a good, workable solution. Sadly there isn't.