# Get info from a JSON file Using Fetch - Cors Policy Issue

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working in a local project with vanilla js. I'm trying to get a json from a local file, but I get an error about the CORS Policy. I already tried with Ajax, Fetch API, and others, but I get the same error. So... It's posible to avoid this Policy with another option?

This is my code:

```
const loadFile = () =>{
    fetch("file.json")
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( content => {
        console.log(content);
    })
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please post your code inside your answer. There is a code block formatter to use, which makes things easier for people answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid CORS error issue just use this `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` and put your url after.

Local Enviroment => If you are using local environment you can simple `{ mode: 'no-cors'}` to your fetch requests it should be all good.

Change your code to this. Should be fine.

```js
const loadFile = () => { 
  //CORS URL
  let corsURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

  //My File URL
  let myURL = 'https://your_url.com/file.json';

  fetch(corsURL + myURL, { mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(content => {
      console.log(content);
    })
}

loadFile()
```

Comment: @ChristianElíasCruzGonzález It should work fine on local env as well. Just specify where the file.json is.

Comment: That is the problem! When I load the page, in the console, I recive an error about the CORS Policy

Comment: @ChristianElíasCruzGonzález If file.json is local server you should NOT even see CORS issue. Something else is wrong there.

Comment: I think the same

Comment: @ChristianElíasCruzGonzález I have edited my answer please try now.

Comment: Yeah! This is the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristianElíasCruzGonzález You are welcome. Glad i was able to help  you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp) (JSON with Padding) method for getting around the CORS restrictions.